LinkGenerator.GetUriByPage method not working
OK, I have solved my problem - the one described below. I removed the Route Pattern constraint 'alpha' and replaced it with 'regex(^([0-9]+-){{5}}[0-9]+$)}', which did the trick. The 'alpha' constraint only accepts alpha characters and not alpha-numeric. My string consists of numeric values with hyphens only. The regex did the trick. The route pattern now looks like - @page "/account/login/{loginRequestToken:regex(^([0-9]+\-){{5}}[0-9]+$)}" and NOT /account/login/{loginRequestToken:alpha.

Problem statement below solved as above.

I have written some code to generate an absolute Url with ASP.Net Core (NET 8.0)'s LinkGenerator class, but for some reason it's not generating the Url. Here is the code snippet in text and as an image:
string loginRequestToken = createUserCommandResponse.LoginRequestToken;

var redirectToUrl = _linkGenerator.GetUriByPage(page: "/Account/Login",
                                                handler: null,
                                                values: new { loginRequestToken },
                                                scheme: "https",
                                                host: new HostString("localhost:7212"));


Stepping through the code with the debugger I can see that the linkgenerator's Endpoints collection contains the "/Account/Login" page with RoutePattern "account/login/{loginRequestToken:alpha}". The parameters passed to the GetUriByPage method are correct. See the image below for a view of the debugger results:

The above code worked till a few days ago, but now, for some unknown reason, it stopped to generate the link. Only a null value is returned. I am using Razor Pages.
Any ideas / suggestions how I can fix this issue? The url is required for insertion into emails generated by the app.
I was expecting an absolute URL that looks like this: "https://localhost:7212/account/login/34333332-54881777777-3385184744-464320895-2720260-7718198683/". This is one of the links generated by this code until it ceased to work. Now I only get a null value.
I triple checked all code declarations and route template declarations. The login page is decorated with the following route template that corresponds with what the linkgenerator have:
@page "/account/login/{loginRequestToken:alpha}"

I have also inspected all variables thru the debugger and the values checked out.
